# No resource identifier found for attribute 'name' in package 'com.jobstoday.joie'

Tags: android, xml

[code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VP3Ji.png)i tried a few solutions provided online for this error,but it is still here.i tried replace xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" to xmlns:SplashActivity="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.jobstoday.joie",but it came out more errors instead.
error is at line 31.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

  <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:mi="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="60dp"
    android:paddingRight="60dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp">

    <view
        style="@style/Jobs.PageHeader"
        class="mi.StyledTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Search"
        android:textColor="@color/joie_green"
        android:typeface="serif"
        mi:font="VAGRounded-Bold.ttf" /> <view
        style="@style/EditText.Outline"
        class="mi.StyledEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/common_spacing_major"
        android:hint="keyword: job type, company"
        android:typeface="serif"
        mi:font="VAGRounded-Light.ttf"
        mi:name="request"
        mi:property="zone" />

    <view
        android:id="@+id/btn_search"
        style="@style/Button.Red"
        class="mi.StyledButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/common_spacing"
        android:text="@string/search"
        android:typeface="serif"
        mi:font="VAGRounded-Light.ttf" />

    <view
        style="@style/Jobs.BodyText"
        class="mi.StyledTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/common_spacing_major_extra"
        android:text="Filter Options"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:typeface="monospace"
        mi:font="VAGRounded-Light.ttf" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/common_spacing_major"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <view
            android:id="@+id/search_region"
            style="@style/EditText.Outline"
            class="mi.StyledDropDown"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_arrow_down_tight"
            android:hint="location"
            android:typeface="serif"
            mi:font="VAGRounded-Light.ttf"
            mi:name="request"
            mi:property="region" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/common_spacing"
            android:background="@null"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_location"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <view
        android:id="@+id/search_salary"
        style="@style/EditText.Outline"
        class="mi.StyledDropDown"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/common_spacing_text"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_arrow_down_tight"
        android:hint="hourly salary"
        android:typeface="serif"
        mi:font="VAGRounded-Light.ttf"
        mi:name="request"
        mi:property="salary" />

    <view
        android:id="@+id/search_category"
        style="@style/EditText.Outline"
        class="mi.StyledDropDown"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/common_spacing_text"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_arrow_down_tight"
        android:hint="category"
        android:typeface="serif"
        mi:font="VAGRounded-Light.ttf"
        mi:name="request"
        mi:property="industry" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Keep `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`. Can you post your code which raised the error ?

Comment: Post your code, not a screenshot please. (Post the full view from line 31 to ...)

Comment: black line shows your package name style does not contains that particular style put proper attrs and styles for finding resources.